# How to deny a page to be accesed directly ,access only with login

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have 2 textboxes and 1 button , the login page.
The password is crypted into a hash then compared with the hash pass in the database , how can i make on button1 to access admin page but only If you are logged in and also if you access the admin page directly in browser and you are not logged it. Shouldnt work and redirects you to login page.

Thankss

Comment: Which version of ASP.NET are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use FormsAuthentication. You don't have to use the Login control, just roll your own. Here's one simple tutorial to get you started: http://bradkingsley.com/securing-asp-net-pages-forms-authentication-c-and-net-4/.

I'll try to find something that covers authenticating to a database, or write one myself, if I can't find a better sample.

HTH.

**EDIT:**

Here are two fairly extensive tutorials from Scott Mitchell that show how to use the web.config file to secure pages:

*User-based:* http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/user-based-authorization-cs

*Role-based:* http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs

Best-practice says to use roles rather than specific users, but the second tutorial builds on the first, so I suggest reading them both.

Comment: K what about the admin page, it can be accesed Directly via browser url

Answer (score 0):

I think u are using Forms Authentication. There is a property called ReturnUrl u need to assign the url redirect after successful login. take a look at this url

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240

Comment: i'm not using asp net login form i used 2 txtb and 1 btn